# how to run proj without solution file in visual studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

friends i am trying to work with predesigned visual studio dotNet projects. so i have downloaded a sample project from internet, al those files doesnt contain files of type"Microsoft Visual Studio Solution","Visual Studio Solution User Options"..and i dont know to run those project without those files.

plz help me to run those projects in visual studio 2008 plz.

f it s not possible plz tel me were to get sample projects with solution files.i would like to work with vb.net and c#.net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply open the project (`.cproj` or `.vbproj`) file. A solution file will automatically be created for it.